# Stying this Simple Typing Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I style each word from the 'data-rotate' attribute with a different background color?
I would like a different background color whenever different words are typed out
The code as below

https://codepen.io/CheeseTurtle/pen/jzdgI

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 3em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: #aaa
}

h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>This pen is
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'></span>
</h1>
<h2>A single &lt;span&gt; is all you need.</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following. Have used [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), [CSS var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). With math random you can pick random colors from an array of colors. In the example the array of colors match CSS color classes.

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
  this.colors = ['blue', 'red', 'native'];
  this.color = this.colors[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length) ];
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }
  

  this.el.innerHTML = `<span class="wrap ${this.color}">${this.txt}</span>`;

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
  this.color = this.colors[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length) ];
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
:root {
 --text-color: #aaa;
}

html,body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 3em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.red {
 color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.native {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.txt-rotate {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>This pen is
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'></span>
</h1>
<h2>A single &lt;span&gt; is all you need.</h2>
```